# Why doesn't delegate work in SwiftUI with UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

Here's a sample code snippet for a video player in SwiftUI, where the player's core is implemented in UIKit (specifically in `PlayerViewController`):

```swift
struct Page: View {
    let delegate = Delegate()
    @State private var isPlay = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PlayerView(delegate: delegate)
            Button("Play") { delegate.play() }
        }
    }
}
class Delegate {
    var controller: PlayerViewController? = nil
    func play() { controller?.play() }
    func pause() { controller?.pause() }
}
struct PlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let delegate: Delegate
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let c =  PlayerViewController()
        delegate.controller = c
        return c
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) { }
}
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
    func play() { ... }
    func pause() { ... }
}
```

In the code above, the page correctly displays the `PlayerViewController`, and the video plays without issue. However, I have run into a problem when trying to call functions like `play` or `pause` on the video.

I created a delegate (the `Delegate` class) to encapsulate these functions, passing the delegate to `PlayerView`, and assigned `delegate.controller = c` in the `makeUIViewController` method.

Unfortunately, when I tap the play button, I discovered that the `controller` is nil.

I'm puzzled as to why this delegate isn't functioning as expected. Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong, and guide me on how to fix it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Additionally, I replicated the same scenario in a playground, and everything appears to be working as expected:

```swift
class City {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    func say() { print("hello I am \(name)") }
}
class Delegate {
    var city: City? = nil
    func sayFromDelegate() {
        city?.say()
    }
}
struct Person {
    let name: String = "Person"
    let delegate: Delegate
    func foo() {
        let c = City(name: "QingDao")
        delegate.city = c
    }
}
let d = Delegate()
let p = Person(delegate: d)
p.foo() // force bind delegate
d.sayFromDelegate() // hello I am QingDao
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View structs are ephemeral so can't hold onto objects so your `let delegate = Delgate()` is a memory leak.

You need to either pass a closure or a binding to your UIViewControllerRepresentable and implement the update func to update the view controller if these values have changed from the last time update was called.

Eg

```
@Binding var myBinding : Int

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    uiViewController.someValueChanged = { x in
        myBinding = x
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've understood the previous issue, but now I'm facing another challenge: how can I retrieve the property value from inside a view controller? For instance, suppose there's a timer within the view controller that continuously updates a random value. How can I access the exact value of this property within SwiftUI? Any guidance or examples would be highly valuable!

Comment: In my answer I said to pass in a binding to your representable. Then in update set a closure on your view controller that sets the binding. So your view controller needs a closure param like didUpdateTimerValue.

Comment: Added some code